# Showing a users email from firebase authentication in a label

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, email, label

I have this email label where the label should show the current users email address, it has worked before so i am unsure as to why it is not working.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

          self.emailLabel.text = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is possibility that email address isn't registered in Firebase. (you need to check if debugger for that)
2. you can always create a database within a Firebase from where you can maintain Account details of users, that way you will know what data you have and what can\can't be retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the user is currently loggedIn. Actually after some user will automatically logout from the application. So please log in again into the app then the label will update automatically.

**Update:**
Just print the description of `Auth.auth().currentUser?.email`. If you will get value in print statement then your label will automatically update as per your requirement. One more thing, Please ensure you have given correct reference outlet to the specific label.